# Proof that if a set $C$ is compact and a function $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $C$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Edwards's Multivariable Calculus gives both the proposition in the title and a proof of the proposition in his Theorem 8.9:

Suppose, to the contrary, that there is a real $\epsilon > 0$ such that, for every integer $n > 0$, there are points $x_{n}, y_{n}$ of $C$ such that 
$$|x_{n} - y_{n}| < \frac{1}{n}\ and\ |f(x_{n}) - f(y_{n})| \geq \epsilon.$$
Since $C$ is compact we can find an $a$ in $C$ such that
$$x_{n} \to a, y_{n} \to a.$$
And then he says "we have an easy contradiction to the continuity of $f$ at $a$", which I do not see.

Would you please tell me where is this contradition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $x_n \rightarrow a$ implies $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ Similarly for $y_n$.

Hence, for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \leq |f(x_n)-f(a)|+|f(y_n)-f(a)|< \epsilon$$

for all $n$ sufficiently large.